# How can I watch full games of Halo 5 from the web?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

How can I watch Halo 5 Guardian games that I played in from the web without making it into a clip using Xbox dvr or use any other recording methods? The games are accessible through my history on the Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, you can't view your games online without recording them with Xbox DVR (and then uploading them).

Comment: You can,actually. twitch is an example of this

Comment: @Timelord64 this is not what I was asking

Comment: @Timelord64 you know CS:GO competitive replays? this is similar to that. He is asking if he can watch them directly online, without downloading, rendering and uploading them first. IDK of any games that allow this though :(